# Program counting 0 as even

Tags: java

I am trying to make sure my program does not count zero as an even and specifically wrote that it must fit these conditions. But it still counts it!??!?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

     public class CountDigits
    {

     public static void main (String []Args)
    {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a number:");
      long input = (keyboard.nextLong());
      String inputString = Long.toString(input);
      char [] inputChar = (inputString.toCharArray());



  int numOdds = 0;
  int numEvens = 0;
  int numZeros = 0;


  int i = 0;

  while (i<inputString.length())
  {

     if (inputChar[i]!=0&&inputChar[i]%2==0)
     { 
        numEvens++;

     }
```

Comment: What is `inputChar` and what is `inputString`? Share the full code

Comment: Have you tried converting `inputChar` to number?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `char[]`, rather than an `int[]`. The `char` `0` is different from the `char` `'0'`. Your program will work if you do this:

```
if (inputChar[i]!='0' && inputChar[i]%2==0)
```

However it's probably less confusing if you use an `int[]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to run your code I can see that you are doing `inputChar[i]%2==0`

`inputChar[i]%2` will return the remainder of `inputChar[i]/2` so where inputChar[i] has the value 0, 0 divide 2 will equal 0 so there will be a remainder of 0.

If you want to count 0 as odd you will also need to check for 0.

Please note that inputChar[i] is a char and not an int so you will need to check  inputChar[i] != '0'